# Why does ComboBox popup customization reference delegateModel?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquickcontrols2

In the Qt QML documentation on [customizing the Quick Controls 2 ComboBox](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html#customizing-combobox), it shows:

```
popup: Popup {
    y: control.height - 1
    width: control.width
    implicitHeight: contentItem.implicitHeight
    padding: 1

    contentItem: ListView {
        clip: true
        implicitHeight: contentHeight
        model: control.popup.visible ? control.delegateModel : null
    ...
```

**Why does it reference `control.delegateModel` instead of just `control.model`?**

Where is this `delegateModel` property documented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delegates present the data items. A `delegateModel` combines the model and the prototypical delegate that will be instantiated for each item. Its key properties are `model` and `delegate`. The [`DelegateModel`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-models-delegatemodel.html) is an implementation of this concept provided in `QtQml.Models`.

The `delegateModel` concept is an outgrowth of having the separate `delegate` and `model` properties. Eventually, more properties were added that always accompanied situations where both models and delegates were used, and instead of adding them directly to the control, they were encapsulated in a dedicated object.

Comment: But where is the delegateModel declared?  If I look at all properties and inherited properties of ComboBox, it isn't listed.  If I create a custom property bound to delegateModel.model I receive an error `QQmlExpression: Expression qrc:/... depends on non-NOTIFYable properties: QQmlDelegateModel::model`

Comment: @DavidJ Yes, it is defined as a non-NOTIFYable property and cannot be bound. You can check this in the [source code](https://github.com/cedrus/qt/blob/f215ae45c75f7f15cab4f5ad8bda48104725a55e/qtdeclarative/src/qml/types/qqmldelegatemodel_p.h#L73). you are only able to assign it to a variable. To connect and bind it, you should directly use the model.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I have been able to figure out:

`ComboBox.delegateModel` is a `DelegateModel` internal to the ComboBox item. The documented `ComboBox.delegate` and `ComboBox.model` will be set as the corresponding properties of this `delegateModel`.

By default the `contentItem` of `ComboBox.popup` will be a `ListView`, which will use this `delegateModel` as its model. The code you show customizes the `contentItem`, but wants to preserve the delegate model behavior, so it needs to use the undocumented `ComboBox.delegateModel` as the model.